# Why the circle inside my React.Portal() fail to align vertical and horizontaly at the center of my div?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

Here the demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-xa23hx?file=index.js

I am using this solution to align the element - SCSS' snippet:

```
%loader__ripple_circle{
  ...
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  ...
 }
@extend %loader__ripple_circle
```

The element are intended to be align in my modal -ReactJS' snippet:

```
generateLoader=()=>(
    <div className="multi-ripple">  
      <div className="multi-ripple__first-circle"></div>
      <div className="multi-ripple__second-circle"></div>
    </div>
  )

  render() {
    let {generateLoader}=this
    let loaderModalDOM=document.getElementById("loader__modal")
    // return generateLoader()
    return  createPortal(generateLoader(), loaderModalDOM)
  }
```

that said the circle are lagged toward the bottom-right of the screen. How to make them on the center?

I have tried to explore the possibilities offered by `transform-origin` also, and seems the problem is elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I have succeed to center my div using flexbox and removing the transform:translate's placement.

The demo have been updated: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-xa23hx?file=style.scss

```
%loader__ripple_circle{
    position: absolute; 
    width: 10vw;
    height: 10vw;
    // fail to center with transform translate
    /*top:50%;
    left:50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%); */
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 0.3rem solid grey;
    animation:ripple 1.5s infinite;
}

.multi-ripple {
  z-index:300;
  position: fixed;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  width: var(--scrollbar-free-full-screen-width);
  height:100vh;
  background:white; 
  // child centering works with flexbox
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}
```